# WebFlux Chaining from Method that Returns Mono<Void>

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Here is my controller for deleting an item:

```
 public Mono<ResponseEntity> delete(
        @PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
    return itemService.delete(id)
            .map(aVoid -> ResponseEntity.ok());
}
```

`itemService.delete(id)` returns `Mono<Void>`

But when i succesfully deleted an item, it is not giving me the response entity object. It only returns blank json.

I seems that map is not executed because delete method returns `Mono<Void>`

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A reactive streams publisher can send 3 types of signals: values, complete, error.
[A `Mono<Void>` publisher is way to signal when an operation is completed - you're not interested in any value being published, you just want to know when the work is done](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#mono). Indeed, you can't emit a value of a `Void` type, it doesn't exist.
The `map` operator you're using transforms emitted values into something else.

So in this case, the map operator is never called since no value is emitted. You can change your code snippet with something like:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity> delete(
        @PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
    return itemService.delete(id)
            .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok()));
}
```

Comment: Is it also achievable by using doOnSuccess?

Comment: @user1955934 doOnSuccess won't change the return type of the chain; it's a side effect.